# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a discord bot with discord.py and focusing with slash commands.
I'm currently having trouble with the suggestion command. The thing that confuses me is that if I do not set the code up as a slash command, it works perfectly with no issues. But since my bot is focused on slash commands, that won't cut it.
**my slash command code**

```
@slash.slash(name='suggest',
 guild_ids=guild_ids,
  description="yas",
   options=[
       create_option(
           name="suggestion",
           description="IDK",
           option_type=3,
           required=True
       )
   ])
async def _suggest(ctx, *, suggestion: str):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    channel = bot.get_channel(947510790360006707)

    suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(colour=0x52b788)
    suggestEmbed.set_author(name=f'Suggested by {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
    suggestEmbed.add_field(name='Suggestion!', value=f'{suggestion}')

    message = await channel.send(embed=suggestEmbed)

    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
```

**the error:**

```
File "C:\Users\my user\Documents\CODes\HAHAHA\skymist\bot.py", line 134, in _suggest
suggestEmbed.set_author(name=f'Suggested by {ctx.message.author}', icon_url = f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

**my imports if you need them**

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
import requests
import json
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error instead of just the message in future, so we know which line it occurred on (as well as other info).

Comment: right, sorry. Ill edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of **ctx.message.author** you should use **ctx.author**

Comment: I tried this and now it gave me this:

`File "C:\Users\my user\Documents\CODes\HAHAHA\skymist\bot.py", line 137, in _suggest
message = await channel.send(embed=suggestEmbed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Comment: alright so i just re invited my bot and the code now works? Kinda weird but this made it work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problems. Have a nice day! :D